# Как сгенерировать случайную последовательность из 5 цифр от 1 до 5 без дублей?

Tags: javascript

Как сгенерировать случайную последовательность из 5 цифр от 1 до 5 без дублей?

Comment: в зависимости от того могут ли быть дубли или нет....... если нет - берем массив заполненный от 1 до 5 и ̶в̶з̶б̶а̶л̶т̶ы̶в̶а̶е̶м̶  перемешиваем например с помощью алгоритма фишера-йетса

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Без дублей.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Всё банально. Берем массив, заполненный от какого-то числа до какого-то, а затем применяем тасование Фишера–Йетса

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  
  // Пока не дошли до конца массива - тасуем...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // берем оставшийся элемент
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // Меняем местами его с текущим элементом
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}


var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr = shuffle(arr);

console.log(arr);
```

Взят код с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/6104996)

Comment: `[a, b] = [b, a]; // Swap`?

Comment: Поубивал бы за переменные вроде `currentIndex`. И за цикл while вместо цикла for - тоже!

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен с while. А с currentIndex что не так? наглядность же. А как лучше?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в реальном коде программист для индекса выберет имя `i`. Или `k` если он приучен букву `i` опасаться. Поэтому `currentIndex` режет глаза своей непривычностью.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Понятно, спасибо, учту-с. Если не против, в данном ответе я пока оставлю как есть, для наглядности?

Comment: Да, надо учиться задавать вопросы. Правильный вопрос был: как перемешать массив.

Answer (score 5):

### Задача

- Получить range(N) - массив со значениями от 1 до N
- Перемешать этот массив

#### Методы получения массива (1..N):

```js
// собираем обычным циклом for
// это самый эффективный способ
function range_for(N) {
 var res = [];
 for (var i = 1; i <= N; ++i) res.push(i);
 return res;
}

// С помощью конструктора Array
function range_array(N) {
  var res = Array(N); // массив из N дырок
  res = res.fill(0);   // массив из N нулей
  res = res.map(function(zero, index) {
    return index + 1;
  });  // каждый элемент массива превращаем в его индекс, увеличенный на 1
  return res;
}

// Укороченные версия range2
function range_array_es6(N) {
  return Array(N).fill().map((_, i) => i + 1);
}
function range_from(N) {
  return Array.from(Array(N),(_, i) => i + 1);
}

// Для разнообразия
function range_keys(N) {
  return [...Array(N).keys()].map(v=>v+1);
}

// Тестируем все:
[range_for, range_array, range_array_es6, range_from, range_keys].forEach(range => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(range(10)), range.name);
});
```

#### Методы перемешивания

```js
function shuffle_reduce(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (res, a) {
    // вставка элемента в рандомную позицию
    res.splice(Math.random()*(1+res.length), 0, a); 
    return res;
  }, []);
}

function shuffle_swap(arr) {
  for (var i = arr.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
    // swap arr[i], arr[j]
    var t = arr[i]; arr[i] = arr[j]; arr[j] = t;
  }
  return arr;
}

function shuffle_swap_es6(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [arr[i - 1], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i - 1]];
  }
  return arr;
}

function shuffle_sort(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
  });
}

function shuffle_sort_es6(arr) {
  return arr.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
}


// Тестируем:
[shuffle_reduce, shuffle_swap, shuffle_swap_es6, shuffle_sort, shuffle_sort_es6]
  .forEach(shuffle => {
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])),
    shuffle.name
  );
});
```

---

#### Объединяем две функции

Выбираем реализации range и shuffle.
Можно добавить их в Array.prototype, только важно, чтобы они не были enumerable.

```js
if (!Array.range)
Object.defineProperty(Array, 'range', {
  enumerable: false, writable: false,
  value: function range(N) {
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= N; ++i) res.push(i);
    return res;
  }
});

if (!Array.prototype.shuffle)
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'shuffle', {
  enumerable: false, writable: false,
  value: function shuffle() {
    for (var i = this.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
      [this[i], this[j]] = [this[j], this[i]];
    }
    return this;
  }
});


console.log(Array.range(5).shuffle());
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
// Array(...Array(5)) - заполняем массив 5-ю undefined
// .map((i, _) => ++_) - модифицируем в последовательность от 1 до 5
// .reduce((arr, elt) => (arr.splice(Math.random() * (arr.length + 1), 0, elt), arr), []) -
//    тасуем массив через "ручную" shuffle
console.info(Array(...Array(5)).map((i, _) => ++_).reduce((arr, elt) => (arr.splice(Math.random() * (arr.length + 1), 0, elt), arr), []));
```